# when my route is placed in child components url is changing but component is not rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

App

```js
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import AppRoutes from "./AppRoutes";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import AppHeader from "./modules/platform-components/app-header/AppHeader";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppRoutes />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

AppRoutes

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./modules/authentication/login/Login";
import BaseApp from "./modules/platform-components/base-app/BaseApp";
export default function AppRoutes() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route exact path="/app" component={BaseApp} />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

BaseApp

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Routes from "./Routes";
import AppHeader from "../app-header/AppHeader";
import {
  Route,
  Switch,
  Link,
  withRouter,
  useRouteMatch,
} from "react-router-dom";
function BaseApp() {
  let match = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <div>
      Base App Component
      <Link to="/app/appheader">App Header</Link>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/app/appheader" component={AppHeader} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
export default BaseApp;
```

AppHeader

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
function Appheader() {
  return <div>App Header Component</div>;
}
export default Appheader;
```

When I am entering url **/app** it is navigating to `baseApp` component but when I enter **/app/appheader** it's not rendering anything but url is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Switch your route with this

```
<Switch>
   <Route exact path="/" exact component={Login}/>
   <Route path="/app" component={BaseApp}/>
   <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>       
   <Route component={() => <div>Not Found</div>}/> // you could also add this line to cater with your 404 routes
</Switch>
```

read more here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md

Answer (score 0):

use Router

```
import {Route,Switch} from "react-router-dom"
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
const newHistory = createBrowserHistory();

<Router history={newHistory}>
<Switch>
   <Route exact path="/" exact component={Login}/>
   <Route path="/app" component={BaseApp}/>
   <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>       
   <Route component={() => <div>Not Found</div>}/> // you could also add this line to cater with your 404 routes
</Switch>
<Router/>
```